# Android Studio for Windows 32 bit

Tags: android, android-studio

Like myself, many found problems when using Android Studio in a windows 7 32 bit environment. I've seen some solutions like manually adding a 32 bit JDK. But is'nt there an actual 32 bit version?

Comment: People down voting care to comment why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who don't know this there is actually a version for 32 bit also. It does not contain an installer but works very well in 32 bit OS. Also it does not have a integrated sdk but can be manually added.

Here is the link:
[Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.3.0/android-studio-ide-145.3537739-windows32.zip)

Comment: Instead, this is the 32-bit version of Android Studio, why it has  `studio64.exe` in `bin` folder?
Do you know what's different between 64bit and 32bit distributions?