# Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working(for android studio)

Tags: java, android

I am using a 32 bit system (Windows 7).
I am having this problem every time I start a new project or open a existing project in android studio :

[image]

Using Java 8.
I have a proper JDK installed;
I have set the path properly both for **path** variable and **JAVA_HOME**.

What am I missing?

PROBLEM DETAILS:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: java.exe
  Application Version:  8.0.0.132
  Application Timestamp:    5316803a
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_130a
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000092
  Exception Offset: 44832bad
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 130a
  Additional Information 2: 130a6d0b6cbfdf0810f8d34ffef65d2a
  Additional Information 3: f373
  Additional Information 4: f3733a088bf3ea20f1f39480b3dbcb86
```

Comment: What JDK version are you using? What are the problem details?

Comment: using java 8.problem details I've given

Comment: Hm, it seems there are [problems with Android Studio on 32 bit systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465498/android-studio-for-windows-32-bit). To me it looks like android studio is trying to load a 64 Bit DLL from inside a 32 bit JVM, which is not possible.

Comment: whats the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Might be, following the steps below should resolve the issue.

1. In the Start menu, right-click on Computer and select Properties
2. In the System properties window, select Advanced system settings
3. Under the Performance section of the Advanced tab, click the Settings... button
4. On the Data Execution Prevention tab, select the Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select option
5. Click the Add... button
6. Browse to the executable that launches Java (or whichever application causes the crash) and Open that file
7. Click Apply or OK to save your changes

Comment: Can't do that either with java executable or studio.System is preventing to do so.